# How can we change views in a UISplitViewController other than using the popover and selecting?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have done a sample app with UISplitViewController studying the example they have provided. I have created three detailviews and have configured them to change by the default means. Either using the left/master view in landscape AND using the popover in the portrait orientation.

Now I am trying to move to another view(previous/next) from the currentView by using left/right swipe in each view. For that, what I did was just created a function in the RootViewController. I copy-pasted the same code as that of the tablerow selection used by the popover from the RootViewController. I am calling this function from my current view's controller and is passing the respective index of the view(to be displayed next) from the current view. Function is being called but nothing is happening.

Plz help me OR is anyother way to do it other than this complex step? I am giving the function that I used to change the view.

```
 - (void) rearrangeViews:(int)viewRow
{
UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

if (viewRow == 0) {
    DetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
}

if (viewRow == 1) {
    SecondDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
}

if (viewRow == 2) {
    ThirdDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[ThirdDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdDetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
}

// Update the split view controller's view controllers array.
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
[viewControllers release];

if (rootPopoverButtonItem != nil) {
    [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:self.rootPopoverButtonItem];
}

[detailViewController release];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have googled and found a nice approach. They use a UINavigationController on the detail view to push new views. You could use this same solution for your project.

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/